# How to operate with times in MySQL (Minutes : Seconds . Millisceonds)?

Tags: mysql, sql, time

I have a table that follows this structure:

**Table Foo**

```
id            time
-----------------------
1           1:30.1234
2           1:29.3874
3           1:03.9123
4           2:11.3847
```

Note that `time` is a `varchar(255)`.

I want to execute a query that returns the lowest `time` in the table.

In order to make this I want to cast into some date variable to do the operations.
The information of `time` has the following structure: `minutes : seconds . milliseconds`.

I tried this query for a first test but it returns `NULL`:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(str_to_date('1:30.1243', '%i:%s.%f'));
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Your time formats are inconsistent.  That contradicts your descriptions of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is wrong your last two times have a . not a :

So with corrected text

> ```
> CREATE TABLE foo (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `time` VARCHAR(9)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO foo
>   (`id`, `time`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '1:30.1234'),
>   ('2', '1:29.3874'),
>   ('3', '1:03.9123'),
>   ('4', '2:11.3847');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT MIN(str_to_date(`time`, '%i:%s.%f')) FROM foo;
> ```
>
> ```
> | MIN(str_to_date(`time`, '%i:%s.%f')) |
> | :----------------------------------- |
> | 00:01:03.912300                      |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(str_to_date(`time`, '%i:%s.%f')) FROM foo;
> ```
>
> ```
> | TIME_TO_SEC(str_to_date(`time`, '%i:%s.%f')) |
> | -------------------------------------------: |
> |                                           90 |
> |                                           89 |
> |                                           63 |
> |                                          131 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT str_to_date(`time`, '%i:%s.%f') FROM foo;
> ```
>
> ```
> | str_to_date(`time`, '%i:%s.%f') |
> | :------------------------------ |
> | 00:01:30.123400                 |
> | 00:01:29.387400                 |
> | 00:01:03.912300                 |
> | 00:02:11.384700                 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=611f0d888a27339867c834b50eee094b)*